# File manager that uses tags/labels instead of folders for GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-management

I love the way emails are organized in GMail. I have long wanted something similar for my local files. The ability to have one file located under multiple hierarchies is a great advantage, and links are not a clean solution.

It seems that there are a variety of [solutions for Windows](https://superuser.com/q/78473/107337), but I am not a Windows user where given the choice. Also, I found [this blog post](http://brib.wordpress.com/2007/10/18/howto-enable-tagging-in-ubuntu-gutsy-in-4-simple-steps/), but the link there is dead, and I'm always hesitant to use solutions from 4½ years ago without looking for newer ones, and I've not been a huge fan of Tracker. Also, there is [this](http://www.pytagsfs.org/) very clever solution, but I want to use this with more than media files—with all files in my home directory, if possible.

Is there a file manager for Linux (or even a file system format) that supports this? I'm willing to try something that is buggy.